# Do I need android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS to enable/disable Wifi?

Tags: android, permissions

I have a (FOSS) app out there which can, among other features, enable and disable Wifi.
AndroidManifest.xml contains `android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`, unit tests on the emulator pass and the feature works on a real device, a HTC Desire running 2.2.2.

The SDK versions are `android:minSdkVersion="7"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="10"`, so I can't say about newer releases of Android.

I have received one single crash report:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider
uri content://settings/secure from pid=6191, 
uid=10114 requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```

Is `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` possibly required on recent versions of Android? The reference says the permission exists since API 1, so I'd be surprised why it wasn't on older releases.

The user message is weird, it just says "lies", so I am unsure if I should just follow this report and add `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,
Torsten

Comment: As far as I know, you just need the access wifi state and change wifi state permission. Seems to work fine for me on 4.2.2 devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird, cause I needed to check exactly the same issue, so i just wrote a few lines of code doing exactly just that : enable/disable wifi and bluetooth.
My conclusion: you dont need the WRITE_SETTINGS permission to toggle the wifi, nor the bluetooth for that matter.

wifi = access_wifi_state + change_wifi_state
BT = bluetooth + bluetooth_admin

(with 4.2.2)

Check whether you were trying something else too, which may trigger the exception ?

Comment: It's what I thought, that android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE is sufficient. There is something fishy with this crash report, as I wrote, I received some strange emails around the same time regarding the app. And it is and was the only such crash report, so I don't intend to do anything about it.